# PDE Book For Self Study

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am a senior high school student from Turkey, I would like to buy a PDE textbook for self-study, as I want to pursue a career in pure mathematics so I would like a textbook that is proof intensive and rigorous instead of one focused an applications and numerical algorithms. My prequistes include baby rudin,  birkhoff Ordinary differential equations, conway complex analysis, ahlfors complex analysis, Rudin real and complex analysis, munkres topology, first half of functional analysis by conway and spivak calculus on manifolds  . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Evan's PDE should be a good one.

Comment: If you feel comfortable with Evan's book, Hormander has a few books that are all challenging and develop good computational skills with distributions. A good PDE theorist should learn to compute to get a feel for what kinds of things converge to what kinds of shapes, especially in cases where heuristic analysis is all you can rely on to tackle a problem at first.

Comment: Besides the now classic by by C. Evans, there isa very nice book by Walter Craig: A Course on Partial Differential Equations, also in the AMS Graduate Studies in Mathematics collection

Comment: Weinberger's [**A First Course in Partial Differential Equations: with Complex Variables and Transform Methods**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/048668640X) is good for self-study, as it includes all the necessary proof details and mathematical background material without going much beyond the level of the typical undergraduate physics/engineering separation-of-variables PDE text. The Dover reprint is also quite cheap. I mention this book in case the other suggestions wind up being more advanced than you're presently comfortable with.